# Accessing classes from another source in C++, issues initializing the constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header

I have a class called Player that has a constructor that takes 5 float parameters declared in my "player.h" file and then initialized in my "player.cpp" file as shown at the bottom of the post.

Whenever I try to run the program, I get the error:

```
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/player.o: In function `Player':
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\Testing/player.cpp:11: multiple definition of `Player::Player(float, float, float, float, float)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\Testing/player.h:20: first defined here
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried getting rid of the "public:" before the constructor, but that didn't help at all.  It says I have multiple definitions of the constructor, but I only initialize it once.  I am sure it is something obvious.

The complete source of the two files:

"player.cpp"

```
#include "player.h"

Player::Player(float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry) {

}
```

"player.h"

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player {

public:

    Player(float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry);
};

#endif
```

Comment: What's at line `20` of `player.h`? Because it looks like you've implemented it there first.

Comment: An empty line? Strange

Comment: What does your `main.cpp` look like? I suspect you may have `#include "player.cpp"` instead of `#include "player.h"`.

Comment: I have #include "player.h" at the top then I call "Player p(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);" in the class as well. When I comment out the object declaration, it runs just fine.  Kind of counter-intuitive though..

Comment: Post a small `main.cpp` that repros the problem. I'm not exactly sure what's meant by, "I call '`Player p(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);`' in the class as well".

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what I just did but it worked.. uh.. ok? I changed nothing and the code suddenly worked.

Comment: @MrDoctorProfessorTyler: a stale `.o` file was being picked up instead of being newly built by whatever script/makefile/build system you were using.

Comment: Well then.  Thanks for the help though!  I learned quite a bit about c++ through this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably haven't protected your `.h` file.

You include your `player.h` in `main.cpp`, there it gets one definition for this compilation unit.
And then it's included in `player.cpp`, where it gets a second definition.

If your compiler doesn't support `#pragma once`, you'll have to manually protect them with **the classical** :

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

// all your class definition code here

#endif
```

Comment: `#pragma once`, as nice as it is, isn’t standards compliant. Please use compliant C++ in answers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It really should be. We're in XXI century, after all.

Comment: @Bartek That’s hardly the point. There are many things that I’d like to be in the C++ standard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're right, I have added the classical method.

Comment: I am already using that though.  I pasted the full code above.  I am thoroughly confused...

Comment: Would this happen if I created an object of the Player class in my main file? Because I commented the object creation, and it runs without error?

Comment: The error message clearly states that both main.o and player.o have a definition...

Comment: @MichaelBurr 's comment is a good idea too. There something that makes the compiler define the function twice.

Comment: Whenever I get rid of the object declaration I have in main.cpp, the error goes away.  I think I am missing something here..

Comment: what do you mean by object declaration ? You also define a class Player in main.cpp ? You can't have two class with the same name, it's not permited/possible.

Comment: Ok nevermind it just worked? I changed nothing and it works now.  What the heck... Thanks for the help and answers though :D.  Any idea why my compiler just decided to start working properly?

Comment: The biggest bug is between the chair and the screen :-). You'll learn that with time :-). Good luck !

Comment: Lol that is true.  I am stumbling over my own blunders all the time!