# Redefinition of struct error, I only defined it once

Tags: c++

I really don't understand how to fix this redefinition error.

**COMPILE+ERRORS**

```
g++ main.cpp list.cpp line.cpp
In file included from list.cpp:5:0:
line.h:2:8: error: redefinition of âstruct Lineâ
line.h:2:8: error: previous definition of âstruct Lineâ
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

int main() {
    int no;
    // List list;

    cout << "List Processor\n==============" << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of items : ";
    cin  >> no;

    // list.set(no);
    // list.display();
}
```

**list.h**

```
#include "line.h"
#define MAX_LINES 10
using namespace std;

struct List{
    private:
        struct Line line[MAX_LINES];
    public:
        void set(int no);
        void display() const;
};
```

**line.h**

```
#define MAX_CHARS 10
struct Line {
    private:
        int num;
        char numOfItem[MAX_CHARS + 1]; // the one is null byte
    public:
        bool set(int n, const char* str);
        void display() const;
};
```

**list.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"
#include "line.h"

void List::set(int no) {}

void List::display() const {}
```

**line.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "line.h"

bool Line::set(int n, const char* str) {}

void Line::display() const {}
```

Comment: Possible dupplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792903/accessing-classes-from-another-source-in-c-issues-initializing-the-constructo/14792927#14792927

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In list.cpp, you are including both "line.h" and "list.h". But "list.h" already includes "line.h" so "list.h" is actually included twice in your code. (the preprocessor is not smart enough to not include something it already has).

There are two solutions:

- Do not include "list.h" directly in your list.cpp file, but it is a practice that does not scale: you have to remember what every of your header file includes and that will be too much very quickly.
- use include guards, as explained by @juanchopanza

Comment: That's what it was! Removed `line.h` from list.cpp as including `list.h` already contains `line.h`. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

You need to put [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your headers.

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

// List.h code

#endif
```

Comment: This is an intro to CPP course. Nobody else is using code like this, I can't either since we didn't cover this in class. Sorry, there has to be another simpler solution to the redefinition.

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was remove `#include line.h` in my `list.cpp`. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @eveo you really must use include guards. Otherwise you'll run into the same problem later on. But it is good to remove unnecessary include dependencies like you have done.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind in the future, for the scope of this intro course however it isn't necessary/allowed.

Comment: @user124384 And what is the relevance of that? You have not even described a problem.

Comment: usign include guards helped me alot and solved my problem , i don't understand it though.

Answer (score 2):

You are including "line.h" twice, and you don't have include guards in your header files.

If you add something like:

```
 #ifndef LINE_H
 #define LINE_H
 ... rest of header file goes here ... 
 #endif
```

to your header files, it will all work out fine.